# add trailing slash in a existing rewrite rule .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rewrite rules in my *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=[a-z]{2}(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|it) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:[a-z]{2}/)?(.*)$ /it/$1 [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Everything works perfectly, but how can I modify them to add a trailing slash if I access the website from:

```
http://mydomain.com/en
```

In this way, I actually get a 404.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your code like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=[a-z]{2}(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|it) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:[a-z]{2}/)?(.*)$ /it/$1 [L,NC,R]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,NC,R]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule before the rules that you already have:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```